# Sample multinomial distribution from the log-probabilities

Tags: r, simulation, multinomial

I have three numbers:

```r
lp_1 <- -316480
lp_2 <- -85041
lp_3 <- -1197042
```

The goal is to sample a multinomial distribution with probabilities proportional to the `exp(lp_i)`. With these numbers, one gets `0` if one takes the exponential, and even if we set one number to `0`, we will not manage to get some probabilities proportional to `exp(lp_i)` because we will get either `0` or `Inf` when taking the exponential of the two other numbers.

Do you see any way to achieve this goal nevertheless? I think it's impossible, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally we could do this without loss of generality by subtracting the maximum value (equivalent to dividing through by the largest probability)  but this isn't going to help enough here:

```r
logprobs  <- c(-316480, -85041, -1197042)
lp2 <- logprobs - max(logprobs)
```

Let's see how big these probabilities would be relative to the max:

```r
lp2/log(10)
[1] -100512.7       0.0 -482935.9
```

So the second-most-probable outcome is **many** orders of magnitude smaller than the most probable outcome (larger than a googol, although less than a [googolplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex)).  There is no way, before the sun burns out, that you're going to sample anything but the most probable outcome (i.e., category 2).

---

Double-checking with a simple example to check my math:

```r
probs <- log(c(0.0001, 0.01, 0.000001))
> probs
[1]  -9.21034  -4.60517 -13.81551
> (probs - max(probs))/log(10)
[1] -2  0 -4
```

This correctly concludes that the first and third outcomes are two and four orders of magnitude less probable than the middle.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I had the idea to subtract one value but I thought this was a dead way.

Comment: Excellent analysis to draw the conclusion, +1!

Answer (score 1):

I think [@Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76807826/12158757) has figured out the possibility when with your `logprobs`.

If you have some relative "close" `logprobs` (in terms of the order of magnitude), probably you can `optimize` like below to find a factor `alpha` like below to have the desired probability `p`, e.g.,

```
logprob <- c(-1, -8.5, -100.9)

f <- function(x) abs(sum(exp(logprob * x)) - 1)

alpha <- optimise(f, c(0, 1), tol = .Machine$double.eps)

p <- exp(logprob * alpha$minimum)
```

and you will see

```
> p
[1] 8.182418e-01 1.817582e-01 1.620909e-09

> sum(p)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But we don't need to normalize with `rmultinom`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, I know you need the proportional relationship only for that. I was just used `=1` to set up the objective function `f`, we actually can use any other positive number.